# Retrieve multiple cell properties from Excel in a single call?

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office, com-interop

I need to retrieve the background property (`Range.Interior.Color`) of a few thousand cells. Looping through each cell individually is very slow due to COM-Interop limitations.

Is it possible to retrieve cell properties that aren't `.Text`, `.Value` or `.Value2` from a `Range` containing more than one cell in a single call?

Comment: I just tried this with 30k cells in VBA and it took less than a second, Is your COM interop out of process by any chance? I can't think of other Range properties that return an array unfortunately. I did briefly think about using Excel4 but you would still need to call vba code to call into the (say) GET.CELL function and these don't return arrays anyway so that's not too promising.

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following (written in VBA but can be transformed to C#):

```
Public Sub GetColors()
    Dim ewsTarget As Worksheet: Set ewsTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    ewsTarget.Copy , ewsTarget.Parent.Worksheets(ewsTarget.Parent.Worksheets.Count)
    Dim ewsCopy As Worksheet: Set ewsCopy = ewsTarget.Parent.Worksheets(ewsTarget.Parent.Worksheets.Count)
    ewsCopy.UsedRange.ClearContents
    ewsCopy.UsedRange.Columns.EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 0.5
    ewsCopy.UsedRange.Rows.EntireRow.RowHeight = 5#
    ewsCopy.UsedRange.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    ewsCopy.Delete
End Sub
```

This code puts a bitmap on the clipboard. This bitmap is created from a copy of the worksheet, however, cell contents are removed, so you will see only the background of the cell, furthermore rows and columns are of the same height and length. Your C# program can then acquire this bitmap and get individual pixels considering that the location of cells can be calculated easily since rows and columns have the same height and width.

I know it's only a workaround but I don't think there was any better solution. It is one way only (cannot write, only read), and difficult to extend to other properties (maybe to border and font colors).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but its not trivial, so I'm not really sure if its worth the hassle trying to emulate a similar behavior.

Basically you need to create a macro in Excel that does the work for you, and then simply bring back the results once the macro has finished. This basically emulates the behaviour of `Value`. I'm not really sure why MS decided to not implement all properties in `Range` to behave the same way, wierd.

In order to do this you need to reference the `Microsoft Visual Basic for Application Extensibility 5.3` COM library. This gives you the required tools to dynamically build and add macros to an Excel workbook.

The first step is to create a method that adds a module and the desired macro to the workbook you are interacting with (you could also open a blank workbook and create the macro there if you are using the function on different sheets you are opening and closing).

The following example adds a macro that returns an array with all the cell colors in the specified range. This is written in VBA, I don't have VS with me but the C# version should be pretty straightforward to port.

```
Sub AddCode()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim xPro As VBIDE.VBProject
   Dim xCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
   Dim xMod As VBIDE.CodeModule

   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

   With wb
       Set xPro = .VBProject
       Set xCom = xPro.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
       Set xMod = xCom.CodeModule

       With xMod
           .AddFromString "Public Function GetInteriorColors(r As Range) As Variant" & vbCrLf & _
                          "    Dim colors() As Long" & vbCrLf & _
                          "    Dim row As Integer" & vbCrLf & _
                          "    Dim column As Integer" & vbCrLf & _
                          "    ReDim colors(r.Rows.Count - 1, r.Columns.Count - 1)" & vbCrLf & _
                          "    For row = 1 To r.Rows.Count" & vbCrLf & _
                          "        For column = 1 To r.Columns.Count" & vbCrLf & _
                          "            colors(row - 1, column - 1) = r.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color" & vbCrLf & _
                          "        Next" & vbCrLf & _
                          "    Next" & vbCrLf & _
                          "    GetInteriorColors = colors" & vbCrLf & _
                          "End Function"
       End With
   End With
End Sub
```

Something to note; I'm sometimes getting a weird error when executing `AddFromString`. The macro code is added correctly to the module but I sometimes get an error; swallowing it doesn't seem to be harmful but if you have the same issue I'd look into it.

Now, once you have the macro, bringing back the result is easy (again, written in VBA):

```
Public Function GetColors(r As Range) As Long()
    //Note the absolute path to the macro; this is probably needed if the macro is in a different workbook.
    GetColors = Application.Run(ActiveWorkbook.Name & "!GetInteriorColors", r)
End Function
```

Comment: I think your solution also needs multiple round-trips. But instead of between the OP's application and Excel, between VBE and Excel. In the line colors(row - 1, column - 1) = r.Cells(row, column).Interior.Color you access the cells individually.